# What language should I use for developing this website?

Tags: php, asp.net, programming-languages

I'm not completely sure whether this question is considered off topic, so please do forgive me if it is.

I want to develop a website that is a bit like a flowchart --> graphics website. That is, the user is presented with a question nr. 1, then he/she can either choose Answer 1A or 1B. Based on whether 1A or 1B was chosen, a new question nr. 2 appears until there's a final statement, that the user gets in the end.

Example:

> Q1: Do you have hypertension?
>
> > A: Yes or No
>
> Q2 (the user chose yes in Q1): What's your blood pressure?
>
> > A: *some number*
>
> Q2B: (The user chose no in Q1): Do you have high blood suger levels?
>
> > A: Yes or no

And so on.. When the user then answers all question in the "path" of the flowchart, he reaches to some statement like "You're in high risk of this and that" or "You should consider excersing more".

In the future -if this turns out to be successfull- I'm planning to make the end-statement be some sort of a report sent to the user's e-mail adress, downloaded as a pdf-file or sent to the user. So - adding features in future is an essential thing when choosing the language (though I'm sure all languages support editing in future :))

But for now, I just need a simple website, that is capable of expansion in the future.

And for that, I have to ask - what language to choose?
I can't say, that I'm a programmer, so please don't tell me to choose the one I like as I probably will outsource the project.

Comment: If you're planning to outsource the project why are you asking us what language to use ?

Comment: Flagged offtopic because of this (in FAQ) : `You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. **Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page**.`

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark: Because I can not outsource it to a PHP guy, if I have to use asp .net and vice versa :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What you're talking about there is the user interface, and the options you've given are languages that are commonly used in doing the back end.

I say backend does not matter for your requirements. There is probably some tasks there to be done, too, but not that much. At least not at this point. The actual app would be mostly happening on the end user browser, and for that I would say - Javascript and JQuery. There are some ready-made plugins for such tasks. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2105905/how-can-i-implement-a-wizard-style-page-using-jquery) for similar discussion for implementing from scratch, but I would think there are more out-of-the-box solutions, too, like [JQuery Tools](http://jquerytools.org/demos/) or similar.

Even though you would not go that route, a framework/platform/language that is concerned with UI stuff is relevant answer to your question, not something running server side.

Comment: it would be nice to know the reasoning behind the -1 :P

Comment: Thanks for your reply and for your kind explanation of forend and backend. I've googled these terms, and I can see, that I have a lot to learn just to know how to outsource web development. Do you have any recommendations of litterature/websites for achieving these skills?

Comment: Well, consulting a professional... Can't think of a book or a web site that I would recommend for the purpose. Although it is a good practice to have second opinions, too, and not just blindly following some quick advises.